# How do you get all the tokens?

Tags: papers-please

In Papers, Please there are 7 tokens, one for each region. Does anyone have a description of what you need to do to get all the tokens?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- **Impor**: Day 4, My Son

> A woman will show up at your desk, all excited to see her son again. grant her access after pointing out the problem with her papers.

- **Antegria**: Day 5, The Couple

> The couple will show up at your desk, with the man having all the correct papers but his wife will have a problem with her papers. Grant her access after pointing out the problem with her papers.

- **Obristan**: Jorji Costava

> Once you allow Jorji Costava access, you will get this token. He eventually will have the right papers.

- **Artotska**: Day 12-16, Engineering

> On day 12 an Artotskan is looking for engineers, and will give you 4 business cards. If you manage to give them to 4 different engineers, before he returns on day 16, you will get this token.

- **Republia**: Day 21-23, The Watch

> On day 21 a guy will come to you with missing papers, and offers his watch as collateral. Allow him access. On Day 23 he will return and will give you a bribe in return of the watch. He notices the watch is scratched and asks for the bribe back. Do so to receive the token.

- **Kolechia**: Day 25, A Lovely Note

> Give the love note you get this day (5th person or so) to the depressed person that comes later this day to get this token.

- **United Federation**: Day 29-30, My Daughter

> On day 29, a man will give you a photo of his daughter and asks you to confiscate the passport of Simon Wenz. He will try to enter on day 30. After you give the passport to the guy, you will get this token.