# What are all the (hidden) achievements in Papers Please, and how do I get them?

Tags: papers-please

What are all the achievements for Papers, Please?

It appears some are tied to [obtaining certain tokens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127138/how-do-you-get-all-the-tokens), but what about the others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to the Papers, Please wiki](http://papersplease.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements), there are 7 regular achievements that are tied to getting each of the 7 tokens as mentioned in the question you linked.

There are also 6 hidden achievements. They are:

> - Glory to Arstotzka - Ignore all EZIC requests and work dutifully (day 31, ending 20)
> - Hired Rifle - Kill the man in red for EZIC (day 23, ending 9)
> - Member of the Order - Help EZIC overthrow the government (day 31, ending 19)
> - Snowier Pastures - Escape to Obristan with all family members (days 29-31, ending 18)
> - Too Honest - Turn over EZIC docs to M.O.I investigator (day 12, ending 3)
> - Worker's Best - Acquire a Class-5 Apartment (day 24 at the earliest)